# "Failed opening required..." error on page load with LAMP virtual host

Tags: php, lamp, linux-mint

I'm trying to use Aptana with LAMP in Linux Mint 17 in VirtualBox. I set up a virtual host site under /var/www and I'm trying to run the site in Aptana. I set up Aptana with the correct URL and document root for LAMP using an external web server. When I run the PHP script I get the following error on the index.php page load (I set up error reporting in the php.ini):

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/LAEWeb.com/public_html/LAEWeb/index.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0
```

I'm using the latest Aptana and LAMP. Does it have something to do with the Apache user vs. the Linux user name?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "run the site in Aptana"? Aptana is an IDE, not a web server. If it has the option to launch the current project, doesn't it just open your project's local URL (e.g. `http://localhost/whatever`) in your browser? What happens if you run this outside of Aptana?

Comment: I got it working. All I had to do was run chmod 777 on all files in the LAEWeb folder. Sorry for posting.

Comment: No need to apologise for posting! Pleased it now works.

Comment: (If you would add a self-answer, and click the 'tick' icon, that removes the question from unanswered lists. Thanks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. All I had to do was chmod 777 on all files in the LAEWeb folder.

Comment: I'm not allowed to check the tick as an answer yet.